# Child div wider than parent with position fixed

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a header with a fixed position in React JS. I have something like this :

```
<div className="showroomHeader col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <div id="sub-header">
      <div className="logo">Item1</div>
      <div className="cartContent">Item2</div>
      <div className="listContent">Item3</div>
      <div className="statusContent">Item4</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The css is as follows :

```
.showroomHeader{
  min-height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#sub-header{
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   display: inline-block;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 9999;
}
```

But my sub-header is wider than showroomHeader.

showroomHeader is like this :

[image: This is showroomHeader]

And sub-header is :

[image]

The content of my sub-header is wider than his parent and I do not see all content of my sub-header :

[image]

Any advice how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    .container {
        width: 1570px;
    }

```
.col-xl-1, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12 {
    float: left;
}

.col-xl-12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.col-xl-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
}

.col-xl-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
}

.col-xl-9 {
    width: 75%;
}

.col-xl-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
}

.col-xl-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
}

.col-xl-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

.col-xl-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
}

.col-xl-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
}

.col-xl-3 {
    width: 25%;
}

.col-xl-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
}

.col-xl-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
}
```

}

Styles of a inner div's :

```
.logo, .cartContent{
   display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.listContent{
   display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.statusContent{
   display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: It can be done on that way, but is there any cleaner and better way?

Comment: Or `width:99%`? I'm not so familiar with css

Comment: position fixed element doesn't based style from parent.

Comment: Ok but it's wider also than a body.

Comment: and if you add `class="xl-12"` to sub-header ?

Comment: @JordiFlores The same problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have defined a css class that does not exist in Bootstrap. There are no `xl` devices, only `xs`, `sm`, `md` and `lg`. See more info at [**Bootstrap Grid System**](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

Other than that, your code seems to work fine. See demo below. (view in "*full page*")

```css
.showroomHeader {
  min-height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#sub-header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="showroomHeader col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div id="sub-header">
    <div class="col-lg-3">Item1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">Item2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">Item3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">Item4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There must be some other css that causes the issue you're facing. Can you inspect the innermost `div` elements and see if there is any other styling being applied? If so, post them here.

Comment: I've added the styles for xl screens.

Comment: @Boky, fair enough. Those are not presented in your code. Can you inspect your `col-xl-3` elements and post **all** applied css in your post (text or pic)?

Comment: @Boky, you have posted css classes that aren't applied to your `<div class="col-xl-3">` elements. I need the styles that are applied to those elements only. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: No. How can I do that?

Comment: @Boky, right-click on your `Item1` element in your browser. Select "Inspect" or "Inspect Element". Copy **everything** under "Styles" which is the panel on the right. [**screenshot**](http://i.imgur.com/JXI8Lzn.png)

Comment: I solved it with next css : `position: fixed;
    padding: 0 15px;
    z-index: 99999;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` for sub-header.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is i think in "display: inline-block;"; try just block; or you must change html like this:

```html
<div className="showroomHeader col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div id="sub-header">
      <div className="col-xl-3">Item1</div>
      <div className="col-xl-3">Item2</div>
      <div className="col-xl-3">Item3</div>
      <div className="col-xl-3">Item4</div>
   </div></div>
```

because inline-block is not block element an there are breaks before and after, and they take place.

Comment: No, still the same problem.

Comment: if it has 100% width then there is that problem, if it hes width with px than its ok

Comment: `.showroomHeader{
  min-height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  position:relative
}

#sub-header{
   width: inherit;
   background-color: green;
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 9999;
}`   if you use position absolute then it will work

Comment: It will not work. Than it's not fixed when I scroll.